# Syntax error in command line while executing python programme

Tags: python

I have just started using python3.3. The shell looks like this:

```
Python 3.3.2 (v3.3.2:d047928ae3f6, May 16 2013, 00:06:53) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> print ("hello world")
```

It prints hello world correclty, but in the command line it shows error in line 1 (i.e Python 3.3.2 (v3.3.2:d047928ae3f6, May 16 2013, 00:06:53) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32 ) declaring it as a syntax error.

What is the problem??

Comment: Are you trying to do: `print "hello world"` in py3.x?

Comment: Please show the actual error.

Comment: @hcwhsa: probably he wants to do `print ("hello world")` in _bash_ command line

Comment: @justhalf Could be, but it's hard to say anything unless OP provides actual traceback.

Comment: You have shown us the code that works, but you have failed to show us the code that doesn't work. Please copy-paste the precise command line you issued, and the response that you see.

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying the syntax incorrectly on the command line. The correct syntax is:

```
$ python3 -c 'print ("hello world")'
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not an error. That's what appears when you open the interactive interpreter by typing `$ python3`, telling you what version of python you have and other details (such as the date).

Comment: @user26372 Please edit your question showing the full traceback and everything else that is necessary